# How to show remote computers mapped drive path?

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I got this to work locally however on a remote system it doesn't show the path but only the drive letter. My goal is to get it to show the drive path of the remote host.

Also sometimes it doesn't show all the drive that are mapped to the remote computer and I don't know why.

I have tried changing `Win32_LogicalDisk` to `MappedLogicalDisk` but it just results to no information.

```
$DISK = Get-WmiObject -computer $compname Win32_LogicalDisk
foreach ($device in $DISK){
    Write-Host      "Drive: " $device.name
    Write-Host      "Path:  " $device.ProviderName
""
}
Pause
CheckHost
```

Comment: Since most drive mappings are created in the "user space" there is no real elegant way  which is known by me to show these mappings.

Comment: That is a good point, what if it could connect to the remote host and pull the information from the logged in user if the user is logged into the machine? would that be possible?

Comment: You can't remote into a user session with Powershell (the known workarounds : use a scheduled task or use PSExec)

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these examples:

This one...

```
$ComputerName = "ServerName"

gwmi win32_mappedlogicaldisk -ComputerName $ComputerName | 
    select SystemName, Name, ProviderName, SessionID | 
    foreach { 
    $disk = $_
    $user = gwmi Win32_LoggedOnUser -ComputerName $ComputerName | 
        where { ($_.Dependent.split("=")[-1] -replace '"') -eq $disk.SessionID} | 
        foreach {$_.Antecedent.split("=")[-1] -replace '"'}
    $disk | select Name, ProviderName, @{n = "MappedTo"; e = {$user} }
}
```

Or this one

```
function Get-MappedDrives($ComputerName)
{
$output = @()

if(Test-Connection -ComputerName $ComputerName -Count 1 -Quiet)
{
    $Hive = [long]$HIVE_HKU = 2147483651

    $sessions = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $ComputerName -Class win32_process | 
    ?{$_.name -eq "explorer.exe"}

    if($sessions)
    {
    foreach($explorer in $sessions)
    {
        $sid = ($explorer.GetOwnerSid()).sid

        $owner  = $explorer.GetOwner()

        $RegProv = get-WmiObject -List -Namespace "root\default" -ComputerName $ComputerName | 
        Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "StdRegProv"}

        $DriveList = $RegProv.EnumKey($Hive, "$($sid)\Network")
        if($DriveList.sNames.count -gt 0)
        {
        foreach($drive in $DriveList.sNames)
        {
        $output += "$($drive)`t$(($RegProv.GetStringValue($Hive, "$($sid)\Network\$($drive)", 
        "RemotePath")).sValue)`t$($owner.Domain)`t$($owner.user)`t$($ComputerName)"
        }
        }
        else{write-debug "No mapped drives on $($ComputerName)"}
    }
    }
    else{write-debug "explorer.exe not running on $($ComputerName)"}
}
else{write-debug "Can't connect to $($ComputerName)"}
return $output
}

<#
#Enable if you want to see the write-debug messages
$DebugPreference = "Continue"

$list = "Server01", "Server02"
$report = $(foreach($ComputerName in $list){Get-MappedDrives $ComputerName}) | 
ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter `t -Header Drive, Path, Domain, User, Computer
#>
```